# How to change the parameter values in CAPL when using the Description(CDD) object

Tags: diagnostics, capl

How to use `DiagSetParameter()`? In capl I tried giving all the possible parameter to this particular function . my aim is to change the parameter value of a diagnostic service for example I need to send the routine with a particular timing, I am using CDD based objects.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer:

```
DiagSetParameter(diagrequest,"parameter",123.4);
```